# Change string inside curly brackets (option separated by |)

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to change the text between the curly brackets from the following string:

s = `"As soon as {female_character:Aurelia|Aurelius} turned around the corner, {female_character:she|he} remembered that it was the wrong way and would eventually end in a cul-de-sac. Spinning around, {female_character:Aurelia|Aurelius} tried to run back out, but the way was already blocked by the vendor. In this dark alley way, nobody would see or care what happened to some poor beggar turned thief. Should {female_character:Aurelia|Aurelius} put up a fight in hopes of lasting long enough to escape or give up now and trust to the mercy of the vendor?"`

My question is this, how do I apply Python logic to the text in that string so that {female_character:Aurelia|Aurelius} in the text applies the logic of:

```
if (whatever is on the left side of the colon) == True:
    (replace {female_character:Aurelia|Aurelius} with the option on the left side of the |) 
else:
    (replace {female_character:Aurelia|Aurelius} with the option on the right side of the |)
```

A couple of other points to note, the string is getting pulled from a json file and there will be many similar texts. Additionally, some of the braces with have braces within braces like so: {strong_character:is big for his age|{small_character:although small for his age, is a very quick warrior|although average size, is a skilled warrior}}

As I'm sure anyone can tell, I'm still new to coding and am trying to learn Python. So I apologize in advance for any ignorance on my part.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad... it's unclear exactly what part of the problem you're stuck on. You might consider breaking it down into smaller steps.

Comment: @AntonvBR Thank you for your help in making my question clearer!

Comment: @PyPuppy If you created the json I would make that clear and also ask for suggestions. You may also remove some comments to not fill this already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html) to locate the variables and their text replacements. Regular expressions support *grouping*, so you can grab both `True` and `False` in separate groups, and then, depending on the current value of the found variable, replace the entire match with the correct group.

With nested expressions it gets a bit harder, though. Best is to construct the regex in such way that it will not match the *outer* level of nesting. The first time around, the inner braced expressions will be replaced by plain text, and then a second loop will match and change the rest.

So it may take more than one replacement loop, but how many then? That depends on the number of nesting braces. You could set the loop to a 'surely large enough' number such as 10, but this has several disadvantages. For instance, you need to be sure you don't accidentally nest more than 10 times; and if you have a sentence with only one level of braces and no nesting, it will still loop 9 times more, doing nothing at all.

One way to counter this is by *counting* the number of nested braces. I think my `findall` regex does this correctly, but I could be wrong there.

```
import re

def replaceVars(vars,text):
    for loop in range(len(re.findall(r'\{[^{}]*(?=\{)', text))+1):
        for var in vars:
            if vars[var]:
                text = re.sub ('\{'+var+r':([^|{}]+)\|([^|{}]+?)\}', r'\1', text)
            else:
                text = re.sub ('\{'+var+r':([^|{}]+)\|([^|{}]+?)\}', r'\2', text)
    return text

s = "As soon as {female_character:Aurelia|Aurelius} turned around the corner, {female_character:she|he} remembered that it was the wrong way and would eventually end in a cul-de-sac. Spinning around, {female_character:Aurelia|Aurelius} tried to run back out, but the way was already blocked by the vendor. In this dark alley way, nobody would see or care what happened to some poor beggar turned thief. Should {female_character:Aurelia|Aurelius} put up a fight in hopes of lasting long enough to escape or give up now and trust to the mercy of the vendor? Puppy {strong_character:is big for his age|{small_character:although small for his age, is a very quick warrior|although average size, {female_character:she|he} is a skilled warrior}}"
variables = {"female_character":True, "strong_character":False, "small_character":False}

t = replaceVars(variables,s)
print (t)
```

results in

> As soon as Aurelia turned around the corner, she remembered that it was the wrong way and would eventually end in a cul-de-sac. Spinning around, Aurelia tried to run back out, but the way was already blocked by the vendor. In this dark alley way, nobody would see or care what happened to some poor beggar turned thief. Should Aurelia put up a fight in hopes of lasting long enough to escape or give up now and trust to the mercy of the vendor? Puppy although average size, she is a skilled warrior

Comment: Thank you! That works beautifully! Exactly what I needed.